# Abnormal differentiation question

Tags: calculus, differential

I'm facing one differentiation question which is it asks me to show that $\frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{4}}=-\frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{4}}$.

My attempt,

I differentiated so it becomes $\frac{1}{4x^{\frac{3}{4}}}$. Why my answer is not with the question given? Can anyone explain this to me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer you have given seems to be correct. Where does the extra minus sign come from is beyond me.

Comment: $\frac {1}{x^n} = x^{-n} \implies \frac{1}{4x^{\frac{3}{4}}} = \frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{4}}$  There is a minus sign that does not belong in what you have been asked to show.

Comment: Reminds me of an assignment in complex calculus that had an erroneous negative sign, and  half the class "proved" it anyway. You are right. The negative sign is likely a typo.